# Get count of unmapped records in a many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have 3 tables as such

**Product**

| ProductID | ProductDetails |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

**Vendor**

| VendorID | VendorDetails |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

**ProductVendors**

| ProductID | VendorID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

How would I go about finding the number of products that are **not** mapped to a specific vendor.

I tried:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(pr.id) AS product_count
FROM
    products pr
LEFT JOIN vendor_product_map vp ON
    pr.id = vp.product
LEFT JOIN vendors vv ON
    vp.vendor = vv.id
WHERE
    vv.id = 3 AND vp.vendor IS NULL
```

but that doesn't seem right. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `not exists` query should be sufficient:

```
select *
from products
where not exists (
    select *
    from vendor_product_map
    where vendor_product_map.product = product.id
    and vendor_product_map.vendor = 12345678
)
```